# Can MongoDB aggregate "top x" results in this document schema?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : "user1_20130822",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2013-08-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "username" : "user1"
    },
    "tags" : {
        "abc" : 19,
        "123" : 2,
        "bca" : 64,
        "xyz" : 14,
        "zyx" : 12,
        "321" : 7
    }
}
```

Given the schema example above, is there a way to query this to retrieve the top "x" tags:  E.g.,  Top 3 "tags" sorted descending?

Is this possible in a single document?  e.g., top tags for a user on a given day
What if i have multiple documents that need to be combined together before getting the top?  e.g., top  tags for a user in a given month

I know this can be done by using a "document per user per tag per day" or by making "tags" an array, but I'd like to be able to do this as above, as it makes in place $inc's easier (many more of these happening than reads).

Or do I need to return back the whole document, and defer to the client on the sorting/limiting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use object-keys as tag-names, you are making this kind of reporting very difficult. The aggreation framework has no $unwind-equivalent for objects. But there is always [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce).

Have your map-function emit one document for each key/value pair in the tags-subdocument. It should look something like this;

```
var mapFunction = function() {
      for (var key in this.tags) {
          emit(key, this.tags[key]);
      }
}
```

Your reduce-function would then sum up the values emitted for the same key.

```
var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        sum += values[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The complete MapReduce command would look something like this:

```
 db.runCommand(
           {
             mapReduce: "yourcollection", // the collection where your data is stored
             query: { _id : "user1_20130822" }, // or however you want to limit the results
             map: mapFunction,
             reduce: reduceFunction,
             out: "inline", // means that the output is returned directly. 
           }
         )
```

This will return all tags in unpredictable order. MapReduce has a `sort` and a `limit` option, but these only work on a field which has an index in the original collection, so you can't use it on a computed field. To get only the top 3, you would have to sort the results on the application-level. When you insist on doing the sorting and limiting on the database, define an output-collection to store the mapReduce results in (with the out-option set to `out: { replace: "temporaryCollectionName" }`) and then query that collection with `sort` and `limit` afterwards.

Keep in mind that when you use an intermediate collection, you must make sure that no two users run MapReduces with different queries into the same collection. When you have multiple users which want to view your top-3 list, you could let them query the output-collection and do the MapReduce in the background at regular intervales.